# Contiguous Logging of Method ,Calling & Exit time

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, n-tier-architecture

Trying to log the time When Method is Called and When its completed its operation and return the values Exit Time.

this i am trying in N-tier architecture.Like

i. Service Layer 
 ii. Business layer
 iii. Data Layer

Data Layer defined a Method `A`, which is consumers by the Bushiness layer method `B`. Business layer method `B` is Called by Service Layer method `D`.

the Log Will be Like

```
Service Method D Called At {Time Stamp}
Business Layer Method B Called At {Time Stamp}
Data Layer Method called at {Time Stamp}
Data Layer Returned Response at {Time Stamp} .Exiting 
Business Layered Received response from Data layer at {Time Stamp}. Exiting 
Service Layered Received exception from Business layer Method. at {Time Stamp}. Exiting
```

Currently i passing a additional string builder object for this to maintain log and respective time . appending current scope and Time Stamp.

Can i automate this process by dependency injection , so i can avoid passing that extra string builder object.or there is better solution for this.

Comment: Do you really need to log each and every method call? This surely will heavily impact application performance.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sometime we need .like when trying to find where my Dime goes. whose exception eats it.

Comment: Then why not log only the exception? It gives the exact code location in its stack trace anyway. (And you can do it with the same techniques as provided in @Sascha's answer.)

Comment: @ThomasWeller i agree with you on the performance issues but cloud is limitless . logging will be in separate a sync thread,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different approaches you can use to get the desired functionality.

One approach is interception as (for example) Unity provides (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Another approach is to use some kind of aspects. See Postsharp for an example (http://www.postsharp.net/)

Comment: Thanks for Sharing some. this will do for me.

Comment: @joshua Glad to help you. Please accept the answer, so in future other might participate in the solution